# Disconnect user from server using session ID

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I wrote a script that will refine users that are either disconnected or have an idle time of over than 60 min. I've already set-up these parameters and the filter works well, however; instead of disconnecting the specific user in that server, the script disconnects the server as a **whole**

I am utilizing two other functions, one of which I added directly into the script. the other comes from [Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Disconnect-LoggedOnUser-116ea40c) The  [Disconnect-LoggedOnUser](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Disconnect-LoggedOnUser-116ea40c) and Get-LoggedOnUser are intended to work together. I kept the instructions for log out script. I've included my full script in this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/ruslive109/e7bb95974d387f9c47461f1b06fe6360)

Any assistance or suggestion is greatly appreciated!
All relevant code below:

```
Description  
-----------      
This command dot sources the script to ensure the Disconnect-LoggedOnUser function is available in your current PowerShell session 

.EXAMPLE 
Disconnect-LoggedOnUser -ComputerName server01 -Id 5 

Description 
----------- 
Disconnect session id 5 on server01 

.EXAMPLE 
.\Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1 -ComputerName server01,server02 | Where-Object {$_.UserName -eq 'JaapBrasser'} | Disconnect-LoggedOnUser -Verbose
```

<#My script#>

```
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Convert output from CMD's 'query.exe user' to usable objects.

    .DESCRIPTION
        Take the text based output returned by 'query.exe user' and convert it to objects that can be manipulated in PowerShell.

    .PARAMETER Name
        Computer name to run query.exe against.

    .EXAMPLE
        PS C:\> Convert-QueryToObjects -Name server01
        ComputerName Username  SessionState SessionType
        ------------ --------  ------------ -----------
        server01     bobsmith  Disconnected
        server01     janedoe   Active       tcp-rdp
#>


function Disconnect-LoggedOnUser {
<#
.SYNOPSIS   
Function to disconnect a RDP session remotely

.DESCRIPTION 
This function provides the functionality to disconnect a RDP session remotely by providing the ComputerName and the SessionId

.PARAMETER ComputerName
This can be a single computername or an array where the RDP sessions will be disconnected

.PARAMETER Id
The Session Id that that will be disconnected

.NOTES   
Name: Disconnect-LoggedOnUser
Author: Jaap Brasser
DateUpdated: 2015-06-03
Version: 1.0
Blog: http://www.jaapbrasser.com

.LINK
http://www.jaapbrasser.com

.EXAMPLE   
. .\Disconnect-LoggedOnUser.ps1

Description 
-----------     
This command dot sources the script to ensure the Disconnect-LoggedOnUser function is available in your current PowerShell session

.EXAMPLE
Disconnect-LoggedOnUser -ComputerName server01 -Id 5

Description
-----------
Disconnect session id 5 on server01

.EXAMPLE
.\Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1 -ComputerName server01,server02 | Where-Object {$_.UserName -eq 'JaapBrasser'} | Disconnect-LoggedOnUser -Verbose

Description
-----------
Use the Get-LoggedOnUser script to gather the user sessions on server01 and server02. Where-Object filters out only the JaapBrasser user account and then disconnects the session by piping the results into Disconnect-LoggedOnUser while displaying verbose information.
#>
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory,
            ValueFromPipeline,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,
            Position=0
        )]
        [string[]]
            $ComputerName,
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName
        )]
        [int[]]
            $Id
    )

    begin {
        $OldEAP = $ErrorActionPreference
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    }

    process {
        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
            $Id | ForEach-Object {
                Write-Verbose "Attempting to disconnect session $Id on $Computer"
                try {
                    rwinsta $_ /server:$Computer
                    Write-Verbose "Session $Id on $Computer successfully disconnected"
                } catch {
                    Write-Verbose 'Error disconnecting session displaying message'
                    Write-Warning "Error on $Computer, $($_.Exception.Message)"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    end {
        $ErrorActionPreference = $OldEAP
    }
}






function Convert-QueryToObjects
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias('QueryToObject')]
    [OutputType([PSCustomObject])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                   ValueFromPipeline = $true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        [Alias('ComputerName', 'Computer')]
        [string]
        $Name = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    Process
    {
        Write-Verbose "Running query.exe against $Name."
        $Users = query user /server:$Name 2>&1

        if ($Users -like "*No User exists*")
        {
            # Handle no user's found returned from query.
            # Returned: 'No User exists for *'
            Write-Error "There were no users found on $Name : $Users"
            Write-Verbose "There were no users found on $Name."
        }
        elseif ($Users -like "*Error*")
        {
            # Handle errored returned by query.
            # Returned: 'Error ...<message>...'
            Write-Error "There was an error running query against $Name : $Users"
            Write-Verbose "There was an error running query against $Name."
        }
        elseif ($Users -eq $null -and $ErrorActionPreference -eq 'SilentlyContinue')
        {
            # Handdle null output called by -ErrorAction.
            Write-Verbose "Error action has supressed output from query.exe. Results were null."
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Verbose "Users found on $Name. Converting output from text."

            # Conversion logic. Handles the fact that the sessionname column may be populated or not.
            $Users = $Users | ForEach-Object {
                (($_.trim() -replace ">" -replace "(?m)^([A-Za-z0-9]{3,})\s+(\d{1,2}\s+\w+)", '$1  none  $2' -replace "\s{2,}", "," -replace "none", $null))
            } | ConvertFrom-Csv

            Write-Verbose "Generating output for $($Users.Count) users connected to $Name."

            # Output objects.
            foreach ($User in $Users)
            {
                Write-Verbose $User
                if ($VerbosePreference -eq 'Continue')
                {
                    # Add '| Out-Host' if -Verbose is tripped.
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        ComputerName = $Name
                        Username = $User.USERNAME
                        SessionState = $User.STATE.Replace("Disc", "Disconnected")
                        SessionType = $($User.SESSIONNAME -Replace '#', '' -Replace "[0-9]+", "")
                        IdleTime = $User.'IDLE TIME'
                        ID = $User.ID
                        LogonTime =$User.'Logon Time'
                    } | Out-Host
                }
                else
                {
                    # Standard output.
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        ComputerName = $Name
                        Username = $User.USERNAME
                        SessionState = $User.STATE.Replace("Disc", "Disconnected")
                        SessionType = $($User.SESSIONNAME -Replace '#', '' -Replace "[0-9]+", "")
                        IdleTime = $User.'IDLE TIME'
                        LogonTime = $User.'Logon Time'
                        ID = $User.ID
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


$Servers = Get-Content 'H:\demo\computernames.txt'
$Queries = foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    #Query each server that pings, save it in a variable for reuse
    if (Test-Connection $Server -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Convert-QueryToObjects $Server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    }
}

#Open servers are ones that responded to the query.
$Queries |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty ComputerName -Unique |
    Out-File 'H:\demo\session\openservers.txt'

#Use the saved query information, filter with Where-Object, loop over to disconnect. 
$Queries |
    Where-Object { ($_.SessionState -eq 'Disconnected') -or (($_.IdleTime -like "*:*") -and ($_.IdleTime -gt "00:59"))} |
    ForEach-Object {
        Disconnect-LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $_.ComputerName -Id $_.ID -Verbose 
    }
```

Comment: It's doing exactly what you tell it. `H:\WindowsPowerShell\Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1 -ComputerName $Server| Disconnect-LoggedOnUser -Verbose ` Isn't filtered with `Where-Object` at all. So will disconnect everything.

Comment: @BenH I meant to say, that I tried adding ' Where-Object {$_.ID -eq '$Id'} ' but it doesn't seem to work out. am I approaching it wrong? thank you

Comment: Using single quotes doesn't allow evaluation of variables. But that only solves one piece, the other piece is where do you get `$ID` from.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `H:\WindowsPowerShell\Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1 -ComputerName $Server| Disconnect-LoggedOnUser -Verbose` isn't filtered with `Where-Object`. So you need to save the information of which users sessions need to be disconnected, then use that filtered information to disconnect.

Here's one way to approach it, comments inline.

```
$Servers = Get-Content 'H:\demo\computernames.txt'
$Queries = foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    #Query each server that pings, save it in a variable for reuse
    if (Test-Connection $Server -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Convert-QueryToObjects $Server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    }
}

#Open servers are ones that responded to the query.
$Queries |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty ComputerName -Unique |
    Out-File 'H:\demo\session\openservers.txt'

#Use the saved query information, filter with Where-Object, loop over to disconnect. 
$Queries |
    Where-Object { ($_.SessionState -eq 'Disconnected') -or (($_.IdleTime -like "*:*") -and ($_.IdleTime -gt "00:59"))} |
    ForEachObject {
        Disconnect-LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $_.ComputerName -Id $_.ID -Verbose 
    }
```

Comment: thank you for that, I've added your script int my program, however; it does not appear to circuit through all the servers and only does it for one of them (the last one) I pasted in your code exactly as described. I've updated my code in the github gist [found here](https://gist.github.com/ruslive109/59673e6785230d156d5f6a4d0134152b) thank you

Comment: @russell Apologies, my code was saving over `$Queries` each loop of `$Server`. I have updated my answer to remedy the issue

Comment: thank you again! is there anyway I can also have the variables listed out like before? instead of just the disconnect status. thanks

Comment: @russell Just run `$Queries` through you `Select-Object` statement for the calculated properties. Or build a new object with `[pscustomobject]@{}`. `$Queries | Select-Object @{Name='Server Name';Expression={$_.ComputerName}},
        @{Name='Username'; Expression={$_.Username}}, @{Name='Session State'; Expression={$_.SessionState}}, @{Name='Idle Time'; Expression={$_.IdleTime}}, @{Name='ID'; Expression={$_.ID}},@{Name='Logon Time';Expression={$_.LogonTime}}`

Comment: @russell Also if an answer worked for you it's best practice to accept it.

Comment: I added the new object right below the out-file but it is not outputting anything, is it placed wrong?

Comment: I've updated my code with your revisions, however; I am unable to display queries in select-object nor, add the new object anywhere. it just seems to bypass these two things.